# New tag [interference] proposed

Tags: feature-request

There are some questions related to electromagnetic interference (EMI). And there will be probably more, because the whole world becomes more and more electrified.

Could anyone create a new tag [interference] or maybe [electromagnetic-interference]?

[Why would my TV image turn black when electrical appliances turn on?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28002/why-would-my-tv-image-turn-black-when-electrical-appliances-turn-on)
[What's causing the popping noise from my speakers?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28049/whats-causing-the-popping-noise-from-my-speakers)
[Will security system wiring cause interference in data cables?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16159/will-security-system-wiring-cause-interference-in-data-cables)

Comment: added <interference> tag to http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16159/will-security-system-wiring-cause-interference-in-data-cables  Electromagnetic-interference is too long (25 char max)

Comment: a comment on a downvote would improve discussion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on whether the basic question its considered "ON Topic"

- Identifying the source or cause of a problem within your home.

or "OFF Topic"

- Operation of major appliances or questions regarding small appliances.

We seem to accept Electrical systems questions but widely pan electronics and home automation.. You would do well to sell the basic question in chat, first.  At least some discussion will result, and perhaps any bias' can be accommodated.